# Shortcut key for right panel

Tags: gazebo-8

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a short cut key to bring up the right panel in the Gazebo GUI?

I've built gazebo from source on Windows and seem to be missing the window expansion icon that controls the right panel visibility.

[C:\fakepath\gazebo_missing_rightmenu.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14658139123698591.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13629/shortcut-key-for-right-panel/) by [azaclauson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2592/azaclauson/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Have you tried dragging the middle of the dark grey edge of the screen? On Ubuntu three dots show up, but some things look weird on other OS's.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azaclauson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2592/azaclauson/) on 2016-06-14**:
Yep that worked.